# VS 2022 Xamarin.Forms Firebase Cloud Messaging working example

Tags: xamarin.forms, firebase-cloud-messaging, visual-studio-2022

Trying to add Push Notifications to my Xamarin.Forms app, and cannot find any working example to implement Firebase Cloud Messaging.
I mean, not a single working example of all the examples/tutorials.
Can you point me to one, please?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7w2q2D6mR7g

Answer (score 0):

You can first check document [Firebase Cloud Messaging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/data-cloud/google-messaging/firebase-cloud-messaging). This article provides an overview of how FCM works, and it explains how to configure Google Services so that your app can use FCM.

The implementation process in xamarin android is similar to that on xamarin forms.

You can also find  more tutorials in your browser.

For example:
[Implement Push Notifications with Xamarin.Forms (Android) and FCM](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=Firebase%20Cloud%20Messaging%20%20%20tutorial%20%20xamarin%20forms&docid=608047578671099009&mid=90473F5EC6DB0589709390473F5EC6DB05897093&view=detail&FORM=VIRE)

and
[Implement Push Notifications with Xamarin.Forms (iOS) and FCM](https://www.bing.com/videos/search?q=Firebase%20Cloud%20Messaging%20%20%20tutorial%20%20xamarin%20forms&&view=detail&mid=7DFD2C7625C7FF0D41127DFD2C7625C7FF0D4112&&FORM=VRDGAR&ru=%2Fvideos%2Fsearch%3Fq%3DFirebase%2520Cloud%2520Messaging%2520%2520%2520tutorial%2520%2520xamarin%2520forms%26%26FORM%3DVDVVXX) .

Answer (score 0):

it work for me in android version, if you use new firebase cloud messaging (HTTP v1) you should update Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging to latest version (in my work i use 123.3.1.1) and do step below

1. add google-services.json don't forget to set build action GoogleServiceJson
2. add Internet permission and PostNotification permission in AndroidMenifest
3. new file FirebaseMessageing only becuse Xamarin.Firebase.Messaging newer version 121.0.1 don't use FirebaseInstanceIdService

   public class FirebaseMessageing : FirebaseMessagingService
   {
   const string TAG = "FirebaseMessageing";

   ```
    public override void OnNewToken(string token)
    {
        base.OnNewToken(token);

        Log.Debug(TAG, "Update Token: " + token);

        Preferences.Set("TokenFirebase", token);
    }

    public override void OnMessageReceived(RemoteMessage message)
    {
        Log.Debug(TAG, "From: " + message.From);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Toppic: " + message.GetNotification().Title);
        Log.Debug(TAG, "Notification Message Body: " + message.GetNotification().Body);
    }
   ```

   }

If I'm wrong understand somewhere, please tell me.

Comment: Do we need to add `FirebaseMessageing` to AndroidManifest.xml file too as a service tag?